# How to show that a given function has a limit?

Tags: real-analysis

How do I go about showing that the following f has a limit at 0.

f(x) = ($x^3$ + $6x^2$ + x) / ($x^2$ - $6x$).

I know that I am supposed to use the definition of the limit in terms of epsilon-delta but I do not know how to go about finding the corresponding delta that would support | f(x) - L | < epsilon.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

$$f(x) = \frac{x(x^2 + 6x + 1}{x(x-6))} = \frac xx \frac{x^2+6x+1}{x-6}$$

This means that for every $x\neq 0$, the value of $f(x)$ is equal to $\frac{x^2+6x+1}{x-6},$ which is a continuous function.

Comment: So then I would have (using the simplified f(x) you have provided) the following: | f(x) - (-1/6) | < sigma for some delta such that 0 < | x - 0 | < delta. Now I have to find such delta?

Comment: @MattB. You don't have to **find** the $\delta$, you have to **prove** that such a $\delta$ exists. Remember, you probably heard something about continuous functions and the limits of continuous functions in class...